# Error calculation for survival analysis

Tags: survival, standard-error

I would like to get some support from you concerning the evaluation of standard error associated to survival analysis.

I found out that the Greenwood formula can be derived from the Kaplan-Meier method and applied to this purpose. However, I would like to know if the Greenwood formula can be also applied when survival probability is not obtained with Kaplan-Meier but with different methods (e.g. actuarial method). At least, I would like to know if this would represent a reasonable approximation.

Waiting for your answers, I thank you in advance!

Best regards